# Formula for Smiley rating system

Tags: rating-system

I'm using the smiley rating system in my website: Like (Smile face), Dislike (Sad face), and Neutral (Straight face).

I used the formula below for evaluating the overall rating as a smiley and not as a number.

Let x= number of likes - number of dislikes

```
If x<0, then rating = dislike
If x>0 & x> number of apathetic, then rating = like
If x>0 & x<number of apathetic, then rating = apathetic
```

How can I calculate the average rating number/score in such rating system?

Note: I need the score in order to sort the highest-rated stuff at the top and lowest-rated at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using object orientated coding, but either way, if you have 'something' to vote on, I would guess that you also have other information on that 'something', which is stored either in a database or some other medium.

That being said, you can simply store the votes, as an **integer**, with the object being voted on.

**Example:**
You have a posting site, or a blog where users can vote on posts made by other users.

Each post would be stored with information like:

- Who posted it
- The date
- Details of the post

With that information you can also store the upvotes and downvotes for it.

Or if you wanted to take it further you could create a vote object and a relationship to the post if you wanted to store more than just the amount of upvotes and downvotes (additional information like who voted or the date they voted, if for instance you did not want people to vote on the same thing twice).

Something else to keep in mind, always keep track of all the upvotes + downvotes and use logic to determine the display.  Do not just keep a single integer and add or subtract to it.  A post with 1 upvote and 1 downvote = 0 score, is not the same as a post with 1000 upvotes and 1000 downvotes = 0 score, as it got 2000 views, which in its own should account for something.

The correct way to do this:
*I know that you do not want to display amounts, and rather emoticons, but you should still store it in that way and render the display differently.*

- Create an additional table and call it something like vote
- Store information like the voter, date, vote type
- Link the table in a many-to-many relationship between users and votes
- Every time a vote is made, update the table
- Calculate the difference between the ups and downs and display the correct smileys on your front-end, or display it as a number

The "I have a crappy client", "I'm lazy" or "I'm coding on 2 hours of sleep" way of doing it:

- Create a single integer field with the object being voted on
- Increase and decrease that as users vote

Hope I understood the question and this helps!